# express-stormpath w/ react-stormpath: this.context.user doesn't reflect groups the user has recently been added to

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application, stormpath, express-stormpath

Using the express and react Stormpath libraries, I have a fairly unique use-case:

Upon a successful Sign Up the user is automatically logged-in and asked a few questions. Depending on the answers the user gives, the user is then programatically added to specific Stormpath Groups. After this questioning period I then route the user to a Profile page where they can edit some profile data, etc. **I need to know which groups the user is in, in order to render the correct Profile elements etc.**

I think the easiest way to commonly do this is just to use `this.context.user` to determine which groups the currently logged-in user is a part of. However, I notice that even after the user has successfully been added to these various groups, whenever I inspect `this.context.user` I notice that it does not reflect the groups they have just recently been added to. In order to get `this.context.user` to reflect the recently added groups, I need to do a full page refresh which in turn 'refreshes' `this.context.user`.

I am wondering if there is a way to 'refresh' `this.context.user`. I would prefer a solution that does not refresh the page, and I would also prefer having not to call a server-side endpoint to determine which groups the user is in.

Comment: pass the context as props or state, or better use state managing libraries. here is why you should not update your context https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html#updating-context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `GET` to the `/me` endpoint is the best way to "refresh" the user information.

also be aware that [Stormpath has joined Okta](https://stormpath.com/blog/stormpaths-new-path) and that the API will go offline at [noon on 8/17/2017](https://stormpath.com/oktaplusstormpath)